# C++ how can I get the destination ip from a SOCKET pointer

Tags: c++

I am doing a firewall project where I am using LSP(Layered Service Provider) for URL filtering. I want to know how can I get the destination IP from LSP ?

Comment: @André Caron: there is WSPSend() function. I need to get the destination ip from that function parameter SOCKET s. Is it possible ?

Comment: OR may be I can use SocketContext for it. I dont know.

Answer (score 2):

See the [getpeername()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738533.aspx) function.

You will receive the peer's data inside a [SOCKADDR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740496.aspx) structure. You may need to call [inet_ntoa()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738564.aspx) to translate it into an ASCII string in Internet standard dotted-decimal format.

Comment: I remember having a problems with `getpeername()` where it consistently returned the wrong address on one of the two sides. Did this work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there even is a function to extract the IP address from an existing socket. Normally, you need to remember the address you passed to [`WSAConnect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741559.aspx) or extracted from [`WSAAccept()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741513.aspx). Check out the full [winsock function reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741394.aspx) to see if there is any extra function that might extract it from a connected socket.

Of course, if you haven't done so already, you might need to re-structure your application to pass the IP address along with the `SOCKET` handle.